# Combining multiple database table and converting rows to column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this 3 tables and I need to combine it together.

```
tblSites
| Site_Code | Site_Name |
     AA         AaaaaA
     BB         BaaaaB
     CC         CaaaaC

tblWeb
| WebID | AppName |    AppUrl    | ServerName | 
    1      aWeb     www.aWeb.com    ServerA
    2      bWeb     www.bWeb.com    ServerA
    3      cWeb     www.cWeb.com    ServerB
    4      dWeb     www.dWeb.com    ServerA
    5      eWeb     www.eWeb.com    ServerC
    6      fWeb     www.fWeb.com    ServerC
    7      gWeb     www.gWeb.com    ServerD
    8      hWeb     www.hWeb.com    ServerD

tblWebServices
| Sites | WebID | SummaryState |       Last_Check       |
    A       1         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:00.000
    A       1       Critical     02/01/2016 10:00:04.000
    A       2         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:04.000
    A       2       Critical     02/01/2016 10:00:06.000
    A       3         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:07.000
    A       3         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:09.000
    A       4         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:10.000
    A       4         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:12.000
    A       5       Critical     02/01/2016 10:00:14.000
    A       5         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:17.000
    A       6         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:20.000
    A       6         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:23.000
    A       7         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:25.000
    A       7       Critical     02/01/2016 10:00:36.000
    A       8         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:39.000
    A       8         OK         02/01/2016 10:00:40.000
    B       1       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:00.000
    B       1         OK         02/02/2016 10:00:04.000
    B       2       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:04.000
    B       2         OK         02/02/2016 10:00:06.000
    B       3       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:07.000
    B       3       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:09.000
    B       4       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:10.000
    B       4       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:12.000
    B       5         OK         02/02/2016 10:00:14.000
    B       5       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:17.000
    B       6       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:20.000
    B       6       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:23.000
    B       7       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:25.000
    B       7         OK         02/02/2016 10:00:36.000
    B       8       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:39.000
    B       8       Critical     02/02/2016 10:00:40.000
```

This are the 3 tables. I need to get this kind of output I need to get the corresponding Appname per ServerName and also the "LATEST" summary state per Sites. 
Please. Can u help me create this output.
Im okay with 1 ServerName per Codes.

```
**Expected Output**
| ServerA |   Site-AA   |   Site-BB   |     Site-CC     |     Site-DD     |
   aWeb       Critical        OK         No Data Found     No Data Found
   bWeb       Critical        OK         No Data Found     No Data Found
   dWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found

| ServerB |   Site-AA   |   Site-BB   |     Site-CC     |     Site-DD     |
   cWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found

| ServerC |   Site-AA   |   Site-BB   |     Site-CC     |     Site-DD     |
   eWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
   fWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found

| ServerD |   Site-AA   |   Site-BB   |     Site-CC     |     Site-DD     |
   gWeb       Critical        OK         No Data Found     No Data Found
   hWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
```

This is the codes that created by one of expert here.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT tblWeb.AppName ' + CHAR(10)
SELECT @sql = @sql + '   , ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Site_Code  = ''' + Site_Code  + '''THEN SummaryState END), ''No Data Found'') AS '  + QUOTENAME('Site-'+Site_Code) + CHAR(10)
FROM tblSites
ORDER BY Site_Code
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'FROM ( SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Site_Code , WebID ORDER BY Last_Check DESC) FROM tblWebServices ) t 
LEFT JOIN tblWeb ON t.WebID = tblWeb.WebID  
WHERE t.rn = 1 GROUP BY tblWeb.AppName ORDER BY tblWeb.AppName '
PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

The output of that codes is like this

```
| AppName |   Site-AA   |   Site-BB   |     Site-CC     |     Site-DD     |
   aWeb       Critical        OK         No Data Found     No Data Found
   bWeb       Critical        OK         No Data Found     No Data Found
   cWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
   dWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
   eWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
   fWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
   gWeb       Critical        OK         No Data Found     No Data Found
   hWeb          OK        Critical      No Data Found     No Data Found
```

I need to get the AppName per Server like the one I've shown on the Expected Output.

Comment: You have some very bad table design here. Your keys don't match up.

Comment: Yeah. But it's from the database. And we cannot edit the database. So that we need to configure it by ourselves. @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for reminding :)

Comment: You are doing crosstabbing in a SQL query. It's almost always a better idea to do this in a reporting tool instead. Are you using a reporting tool or just exporting to a file that someone opens?

Comment: For example it would be far easier to produce your output if it just had an extra column 'Server Name' which contained the server. If you MUST have it the way you've described then you are describing a report and you should use a proper reporting tool rather than jumping through all sorts of SQL hoops to format the data in a certain way.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay. I'll try your suggestion.. reporting tool like?

Comment: Like SSRS (free with SQL Server). How is this output used? Is someone looking at it or is it sent to another system?

Comment: It is sent to another system